# Using .getDeclaredMethod to get a method from a class extending another

Tags: java, reflection

So lets say I am trying to get a method from a class using `Method m = plugin.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getFile");`.

But that `plugin` class is extending another class, which is the one with the `getFile` method. I am not quite sure if that would make it throw the `NoSuchMethodException` exception or not.

I know the class that the `plugin` is extending has the getFile method.
Sorry if I sound confusing, a bit tired.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to use `getMethod` instead of `getDeclaredMethod`. The whole point of [`getDeclaredMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) is that it *only* finds methods declared in the class you're calling it on:

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified declared method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

Whereas [`getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) has:

> C is searched for any matching methods. If no matching method is found, the algorithm of step 1 is invoked recursively on the superclass of C.

That will only find *public* methods though. If the method you're after isn't public, you should recurse up the class hierarchy yourself, using `getDeclaredMethod` or `getDeclaredMethods` on each class in the hierarchy:

```
Class<?> clazz = plugin.getClass();
while (clazz != null) {
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        // Test any other things about it beyond the name...
        if (method.getName().equals("getFile") && ...) {
            return method;
        }
    }
    clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
}
```

Comment: If it helps, the reason I am using this is due to the method being private in the first place. Annd then you edit. Alright, I'll try the edit.

Comment: @Ultimate: Well yes, that's pretty important. It would have helped if you'd mentioned that to start with.

Comment: Well, this was a while back. Sorry for not accepting this!