# How to set delegated property value by reflection in kotlin?

Tags: reflection, delegates, kotlin

My entity class:

```
class User : ActiveRecord<User>() {
    var name by Column(String.javaClass);
    var id by Column(Int.javaClass);
}
```

now I want to set name value by refelection:

```
var clazz = User().javaClass
var record = clazz.newInstance()
var field = record.getDeclaredField(it + "$" + "delegate")

field.set(record, "aa")
```

then error:

> entity.Column field ActiveRecord4k.User.name$delegate to java.lang.String

how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the delegate with another instance, or just reflectively set the property value like `record.name = "aa"`?

Comment: hey maybe my answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115232/2939453

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to reflectively set the property as if it was `record.name = "..."`, then you can use [`kotlin-reflect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect), the Kotlin reflection API (see [the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/)).

With `kotlin-reflect`, setting a property value is done like this:

```
val property = outputs::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "name" }
if (property is KMutableProperty<*>) {
    property.setter.call(record, "value")
}
```

<sup>If the property is delegated, the call will be dispatched to the delegate.</sup>

Or, you can do that with Java reflection, finding the setter for your property first:

```
var setter = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("set" + it.capitalize())
setter.invoke(record, "aa")
```

But there is no way, at least at this point, to overwrite the delegate instance of that property, because the field storing it, `name$delegate`, is `final`.

Comment: Callable expects 2 arguments ? why ? what is the kotlin-reflect version?

Comment: Oh, it was a mistake in the code, you should actually pass the object and the property value: `property.setter.call(record, "value")`. Fixed this.