# Kotlin, how to retrieve field value via reflection?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

So I have hundreds of fields in a couple of [classes](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/uno-sdk/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/uno/caps/caps.kt) and I'd like to write some methods on them where they automatically `println` each field and its corresponding value

At the moment I have this:

```kotlin
inner class Version(val profile: Profile) {

    @JvmField val MINOR_VERSION = glGetInteger(GL_MINOR_VERSION)

    fun write(file: File? = null) {
        //file.printWriter().use { out -> out.pri }
        this::class.java.fields.forEach {
            println(it.isAccessible)
            println(it.getInt(it)) }
    }
}
```

But this is what I get:

```
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final int field uno.caps.Caps$Version.MINOR_VERSION to java.lang.reflect.Field
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeQualifiedIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
```

Any idea?

Comment: hey @elect check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115232/2939453

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Instead of using Java fields and Java reflection code, you can also use Kotlin properties and Kotlin reflection classes:

```
class Reflector {
    val Foo = 1;

    fun printFields() {
        this::class.memberProperties.forEach {
            if (it.visibility == KVisibility.PUBLIC) {
                println(it.name)
                println(it.getter.call(this))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about java class?

Comment: hey @elect Please check my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115232/2939453

Comment: Is this still correct? I don't see `memberProperties` but only `members`. Kotlin version 1.5.20.

Comment: Yes it's still there: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/member-properties.html

Comment: @DamnVegetables needs `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are passing the `Field` variable `it` as a parameter `getInt` whereas the parameter should be the object the field belongs to `this`:

From the Javadoc for `Field.getInt(Object obj)`:

> [obj - the object to extract the int value from](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getInt-java.lang.Object-)

Perhaps this is what you meant to do:

```
class Reflector {
    @JvmField val Foo = 1;

    fun printFields() {
        this.javaClass.fields.forEach {
            println(it.isAccessible)
            println(it.getInt(this))
        }
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    Reflector().printFields()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you should first add the following dependency:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
    // ...
}
```

Also, to get fields of a static Java class or fields that are static, use
`staticProperties` instead of `memeberProperties`:

```kotlin
// R.raw is a static class in Android and its fields are also static
for (property in R.raw::class.staticProperties) {
    println(property.name)
    println(property.get())
}
```