# Java/Android/Kotlin: Reflection on private Field and call public methods on it

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

Is it possiable to use reflection to access a object's private field and call a public methods on this field?

i.e

```
class Hello {
   private World word
}

class World {
   public BlaBlaBla foo()
}

Hello h = new Hello()

World world = reflect on the h


// And then 

world.foo()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It’s possible to make `private` fields `accessible` using reflection. The following examples (both written in *Kotlin*) show it...

Using **Java** Reflection:

```
val hello = Hello()
val f = hello::class.java.getDeclaredField("world")
f.isAccessible = true
val w = f.get(hello) as World
println(w.foo())
```

Using **Kotlin** Reflection:

```
val hello = Hello()
val f = Hello::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "world" }
f?.let {
    it.isAccessible = true
    val w = it.get(hello) as World
    println(w.foo())
}
```

Comment: How could you access a private val which is not in a class using reflection?

Comment: For properties you may need to do `it.getter.call(hello)` instead of `it.get(hello)`

Comment: Would this work for a `private` Kotlin extension function ??

Answer (score 35):

To access **private properties and functions** of a class in **Kotlin** here are two useful extension functions:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.callPrivateFunc(name: String, vararg args: Any?): Any? =
    T::class
        .declaredMemberFunctions
        .firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?.apply { isAccessible = true }
        ?.call(this, *args)

inline fun <reified T : Any, R> T.getPrivateProperty(name: String): R? =
    T::class
        .memberProperties
        .firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?.apply { isAccessible = true }
        ?.get(this) as? R
```

Usage Example:

```
class SomeClass {

    private val world: World = World()

    private fun somePrivateFunction() {
        println("somePrivateFunction")
    }

    private fun somePrivateFunctionWithParams(text: String) {
        println("somePrivateFunctionWithParams()  text=$text")
    }
}

class World {
    fun foo(): String = "Test func"
}

// calling private functions:

val someClass = SomeClass()
someClass.callPrivateFunc("somePrivateFunction")
someClass.callPrivateFunc("somePrivateFunctionWithParams", "test arg")

// getting private member and calling public function on it:

val world = someClass.getPrivateProperty<SomeClass, World>("world")
println(world?.foo())
```

To use reflection in **Kotlin** add dependency:

> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

Answer (score 1):

Call private function with params using Java reflection:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.callPrivateFunc(name: String, vararg args: Any?): Any? {
    val classArray: Array<Class<*>> = args.map { it!!::class.java}.toTypedArray()
    return T::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(name, *classArray)
        .apply { isAccessible = true }
        .invoke(this, *args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like readable reusable easy to understand solution:

Define somewhere:

```
fun <T> Any.privateField(name: String): T {
    val field = this::class.java.getDeclaredField(name)
    field.isAccessible = true
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return field.get(this) as T
}
```

And use elsewhere:

```
val <T : TextInputLayout> T.startIconView: CheckableImageButton
    get() = privateField("startIconView")
```