# How to call private functions of a class from outside the class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, private, private-methods, private-functions

I want to call a private functions of class `SomeClass` from outside of this class:

```
class SomeClass {
    private fun somePrivateFunction() {
        //...
    }

    private fun somePrivateFunctionWithParams(text: String) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the code I have a reference to `SomeClass` object:

```
val someClass = SomeClass()
// how can I call the private function `somePrivateFunction()` from here?
// how can I call the private function `somePrivateFunctionWithParams("some text")` from? here
```

How to call private functions with params and without params in Kotlin from outside a class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across two useful extension functions, which are using reflection:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.callPrivateFunc(name: String, vararg args: Any?): Any? =
    T::class
        .declaredMemberFunctions
        .firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?.apply { isAccessible = true }
        ?.call(this, *args)

inline fun <reified T : Any, R> T.getPrivateProperty(name: String): R? =
    T::class
        .memberProperties
        .firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?.apply { isAccessible = true }
        ?.get(this) as? R
```

To use reflection in **Kotlin** add dependency:

> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

Those functions can be used as the following:

```
class SomeClass {

    private val world: World = World()

    private fun somePrivateFunction() {
        println("somePrivateFunction")
    }

    private fun somePrivateFunctionWithParams(text: String) {
        println("somePrivateFunctionWithParams()  text=$text")
    }
}

class World {
    fun foo(): String = "Test func"
}

// calling private functions:

val someClass = SomeClass()
someClass.callPrivateFunc("somePrivateFunction")
someClass.callPrivateFunc("somePrivateFunctionWithParams", "test arg")

// getting private member and calling public function on it:

val world = someClass.getPrivateProperty<SomeClass, World>("world")
println(world?.foo())
```

Comment: When using the parameter version, I'm getting: "IllegalArgumentException: Callable expects 4 arguments, but 2 were provided."  Which is weird because the function actually needs 3 parameters.  Could you explain using the parameter version in a little more detail?

Comment: what function do you call which has parameter `version`?

Comment: I figured it out.  Each parameter needs to be its own separate parameter after the name of the function.  I thought the parameters were all part of the String (which was the second parameter).

Comment: I'd like to add that setting the variable should be: `inline fun <reified T : Any, R> T.setPrivateProperty(name: String, value: R) =
    T::class
        .memberProperties
        .firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?.apply { isAccessible = true }
        ?.let { (it as? KMutableProperty1<T, R>)?.setter?.call(this, value) }`

Comment: @Sergio callPrivateFunc is not working in case of polymorphism. When creating 2 methods with same name with different number of arguments.

Answer (score 5):

The idea of "private" is that only you can call it inside your class. If you want to "break in" to that class, you need to make use of reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159066/8073652

From the docs:

> `private` means visible inside this class only (including all its members)

Here's an example:

```
class WithPrivate {
    private fun privFun() = "you got me"
}

fun main() {
    WithPrivate::class.declaredMemberFunctions.find { it.name == "privFun" }?.let {
        it.isAccessible = true
        println(it.call(WithPrivate()))
    }

}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to know how to do it using reflection, but the only hint to that in the question is the reflection tag...

Comment: By the link you provided, I see how to access to private fields of an object, but there is no information on how to call private functions of an object.

Comment: Added an example for a function, it's very similar though

Answer (score 0):

```
val managerClass = Class.forName("com.api.Manager").kotlin
val managerInstance = managerClass.createInstance()
val startMethod = managerClass
    .declaredMemberFunctions
    .first { it.name == "start" }
    .also { it.isAccessible = true }
val param = 1234
startMethod.call(managerInstance, param)
```