# Using Mockito and reflection to call a private function

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I am trying to mock a private function call in kotlin with mockk.  Running into the following error:

> Class is final. Put @MockKJUnit4Runner on your test or add MockK Java
> Agent instrumentation to make all classes 'open'

I fully understand the implications of trying to test a private method, however at this point its what I need to do.

Code:

```
class ClassToTest {
  private fun privateMethod(text: String): String {
    return "Hello $text"
  }
}

class TestClass {

   @Before
   fun setup() {
      MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
   }

   @Test
   fun testSplitNumbers() {
      val clazz = spyk<ClassToTest>()

      val method = clazz.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("privateMethod", String::class.java)
      method.isAccessible = true
      val result = method.invoke(clazz, "Test") as? String
      Assert.assertEquals("Hello Test", result)
   }
}
```

Comment: No. Just make the method `internal` and mark it with an annotation like `@VisibleForTesting`. Also, you can't mock or spy on final classes - that's what the error actually says. Add an `open` modifier to the class and relevant methods.

Comment: Pretty sure that is not true, as it also gives this as an open: "OR add MockK Java Agent instrumentation to make all classes 'open'".  I believe that MockK will make all classes open for testing.

Comment: Why do you want to test a private method? Before even think of using Reflection or Mockito to make it callable, please refactor your code towards testability. If it's not your code, then you should accept it as "black box" and use the public methods only.

Comment: @oliver_t, not my code, trying to get around something at the moment.  Hence my comment in the question that I fully understand the implication.

Answer (score 2):

As [outlined in the documentation](https://mockk.io/#private-functions-mocking--dynamic-calls), MockK supports spying on and mocking private functions.

Just be sure to understand [the implications of testing private methods](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/380296/124750) of a class.

Let's say you use an 3rd party library you cannot control with a class `Foo`, which provides a method `publicMethod` which in turn calls a private method `privateMethod` and you want to mock the latter to ease testing.

```kotlin
class Foo {
  fun publicMethod(): String = "Hello ${privateMethod()}!"

  private fun privateMethod(): String = "World"
}
```

You can mock the `privateMethod` with something along the lines of:

```kotlin
fun `mock private function`() {
  val mock = spyk<Foo>(recordPrivateCalls = true)

  every { mock["privateMethod"]() } returns "Test"

  assertEquals("Hello Test!", mock.publicMethod())
}
```

Comment: So I can mock the private method, but not call it directly?

Comment: @lostintranslation If you want to actually call the private function yourself, you most likely will need to make use of reflection. I'd recommend to take a look at this [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72111931/3160089) for a way how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this please...

```
 when(spy, method(CodeWithPrivateMethod.class, "privateMethod", String.class, int.class)) 
.withArguments(anyString(), anyInt()) 
.thenReturn(true);
```

or

```
    doReturn(true).when(codeWithPrivateMethod, "privateMethod", anyString(), anyInt());
```

or   `With no argument:`

```
ourObject = PowerMockito.spy(new OurClass());
when(ourObject , "ourPrivateMethodName").thenReturn("mocked result");
```

or   `With String argument:`

```
ourObject = PowerMockito.spy(new OurClass());
when(ourObject, method(OurClass.class, "ourPrivateMethodName", String.class))
                .withArguments(anyString()).thenReturn("mocked result");
```