# Accessing private field of TextView in Android 11 using Kotlin 1.5.20?

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

Saw the [exiting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158909/java-android-kotlin-reflection-on-private-field-and-call-public-methods-on-it), but the accepted answer with 22 votes does not seem to compile. The answer is

```
val hello = Hello()
val f = Hello::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "world" }
f?.let {
    it.isAccessible = true
    val w = it.get(hello) as World
    println(w.foo())
}
```

, but `class` has no `memberProperties`. The closest thing I could find is `members`, but it seems that it does not return the correct type.  How can I get the private field "mEditor"?

```
    val f = TextView::class.members.find {it.name == "mEditor"};
    f?.let{
        it.isAccessible=true;
        val w = it.get(text2)
    }
```

> Unresolved reference: isAccessible

TextView.java

```
@RemoteView
public class TextView extends View implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {

....

/**
 * {@link EditText} specific data, created on demand when one of the Editor fields is used.
 * See {@link #createEditorIfNeeded()}.
 */
@UnsupportedAppUsage
private Editor mEditor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getDeclaredField` just like java.

```
    val f = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mEditor")
    f?.let {
        it.isAccessible = true
        Log.d("TYPE:",f.genericType.toString())
    }
```

**Log Output:**

```
TYPE:: class android.widget.Editor
```

Comment: So, why did the accepted answer of that question use `class` instead of `class.java`?