# Kotlin: How to access nested object or property by var?

Tags: object, kotlin, nested

Is there a native way in kotlin to access a nested complex object (parsed from JSON string) through a variable?

Smth similar to:

```
   var = "Obj4"
    a = Obj1.Obj2.Obj3.$var.Obj5.Array[index]
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I think you're looking for reflextion. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html
It's not dymanimacally-typed language where everything is map, so you'll need to find field with reflection.

Comment: Yep, I c. That would be like val name = p.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.first { it.name == "name" }.get(p)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525122/kotlin-data-class-how-to-read-the-value-of-property-if-i-dont-know-its-name-at)

Using the reflection. Don't forget to add the dependency.
Global inline extension fun for Any:

```
 inline fun <reified T : Any> Any.getThroughReflection(propertyName: String): T? {
    val getterName = "get" + propertyName.capitalize()
    return try {
        javaClass.getMethod(getterName).invoke(this) as? T
    } catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
        null
    }
}
```