# workaround for `java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name` on regex Pattern

Tags: java, reflection

`java.util.regex.Pattern` has a method `Map<String, Integer> namedGroups()`. For some reason they decided to make it private, and so there is no way to obtain this very useful information! :(

I've tried accessing this information (read-only) with this helper class:

```
package java.util.regex;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class PatternHelper {
    public static Map<String, Integer> getNamedGroups(Pattern pattern) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(pattern.namedGroups());
    }
}
```

But Java8 complains with `java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util.regex`.

How can I access this information (read-only)?
maybe by reflection?

---

**Update**
This program using reflection fails. Any idea?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test50 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<word>\\w+)(?<num>\\d+)");
        Method method = Pattern.class.getMethod("namedGroups");  // it fails with NoSuchMethodException: java.util.regex.Pattern.namedGroups()
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object result = method.invoke(p);
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection would indeed work. Just call `setAccessible` on the `Method`

Comment: i've updated the question with a example source code to use reflection, but it fails with NoSuchMethodException. any idea?

Comment: You get that error because it is not allowed to create your own classes in a package that starts with `java`. You could do this with reflection, but beware that you are then directly accessing the internals of class `Pattern`, which is an ugly hack and which is not guaranteed to still work on future versions of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMethod` [will only find `public` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17953749/7366707).

Try:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<word>\\w+)(?<num>\\d+)");
Method method = Pattern.class.getDeclaredMethod("namedGroups");
method.setAccessible(true);
Object result = method.invoke(p);
System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

Prints:
`result: {word=1, num=2}`

Additionally, looking through grepCode seems to show that `namedGroups` did not exist before JDK 7 (at least in OpenJDK) so that might factor in as well. I would take caution with such a solution as this is not public API and this functionality is therefore not guaranteed to stay the same in future releases.